# How to improve C++ JSON serializer

Tags: c++, json, serialization, reflection

TLDR: How to improve the serialize method I add to my classes to avoid using the **JVAL** C macro?

Long story:

I've written a JSON serializer/deserializer in C++ using rapidjson to parse the JSON itself and a reader/writer class to serialize to/from JSON.

C++ doesn't have reflection, and I want to avoid external metafiles or precompilation steps, so to implement it I've had to add an interface to every class I want to be serializabile.

**NOTE**: by design my class serialize always from and to string buffers, so I can avoid error checking in the serialize() method.

Here is the simple interface:

```
class RJSerializer;

struct Serializable
{
    virtual void serialize(RJSerializer &) = 0;
    virtual ~Serializable() {}
};
```

The method serialize is the object of my question, actually for an object like this:

```
struct Group : Serializable {
    long long id;
    std::string name;
    std::string type;
    bool internal;
    std::vector<Subgroup> subgroups;

    void serialize(RJSerializer &);
};
```

It's implemented in this way:

```
void Group::
serialize(RJSerializer &s)
{
    JVAL(s, id);
    JVAL(s, name);
    JVAL(s, type);
    JVAL(s, internal);
    JVAL(s, subgroups);
}
```

The object of my question is that **JVAL** that does the actual "magic" using an ugly C style macro, and I'd like to improve it a bit...

```
#define JVAL(w, a) w.Pair(#a, a)
```

This method associate the member **a** to the name **"a"**, then a C++ template method in the RJSerializer class:

```
template <typename T>
void Pair(const char *k, T &v) { key(k); val(v); }
```

Does the initial step to the serialize process... and the rest is similar to every other binary C++ serializer you can find on this planet...

Comment: If I get it correctly, with very little design info, what's wrong in typing `s.Pair("id", id)` and so on ?

Comment: As C++ doesn't have reflection, you have to use some MACRO to avoid to repeat name and variable. You may look at [boost::hana-Struct](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Struct.html) to add reflection to your class without inheritance. (I have personally do similar stuff with [visit_struct](https://github.com/cbeck88/visit_struct) and [better-enums](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums)).